# non linear differential equation plot

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Consider the following paper:

https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0096300306007715?token=2B98E3B12F1E623C99A0787996469AF36E8EF230F6ED5289EAFB60B64CE79A6ACCF74B946A34F3370C65D4FC99018648&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20210825115609

From my understanding figure 2(on page 5) is a graph of $s(t), i(t)$ and $r(t)$ by the function in the appendix(page 6) for case 1.

However, when I try plotting this function, I get the wrong out output, why?

```
Plot[{ 1 - 
   0.36*t + (0.72*10^-1)*t^2 - (0.96*10^-2)*t^3 + (0.96*10^-3)*
    t^4 - (0.768*10^-4)*t^5 + (0.5688888892*10^-6)*t^6, 
  0.36*t - (0.72*10^-1)*t^2 + (0.96*10^-2)*t^3 - (0.96*10^-3)*
    t^4 + (0.768*10^-4)*t^5 - (0.512*10^-5)*t^6}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

The details from the paper since it was pointed out it cant be accessed:

Consider the system:

$$\frac{ds}{dt}=(1-p)\mu -\beta s i -\mu s \quad (1)$$
$$\frac{di}{dt}=\beta s i -(\gamma+\mu) i  \;\;\;\;\;\;\ \;\;\quad  (2)$$
$$\frac{dr}{dt}=p\mu +\gamma i-\mu r \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\ \quad(3)$$

using [Adomian decomposition technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adomian_decomposition_method) we have:

$$s(t) = s(0) +(1-p)\mu t -\beta \int_0^t si\; dt -\mu\int_0^t s \;dt \;\;\;\;\quad (4)$$
$$i(t) = i(0) +\beta \int_0^t si\; dt -(\gamma+\mu)\int_0^t i \;dt \quad \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(5)$$
$$r(t) = r(0) +p\mu t +\gamma \int_0^t i\; dt -\mu\int_0^t r \;dt \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\quad(6)$$

From Adomian decomposition euations (4)-(6) are considered the sum of the following:

$$s=\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_n,\quad i=\sum_{n=0}^\infty i_n, \quad r=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r_n  \qquad (7)$$

Then we approximate non-linear terms by:

$$si=\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_n \quad (8)$$

where

$$F_n=\frac{1}{n!} \left[ \frac{d^n\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty s_k \lambda^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty i_k \lambda^k\right)}{d\lambda^n} \right]_{\lambda=0} \qquad (9)$$

The nonlinear functions $F_n$ are the Adomian polynomials. Substituting (7)-(9) into (4)-(6) we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_n = s(0) +(1-p)\mu t -\beta \int_0^t \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_n\; dt -\mu\int_0^t \sum_{n=0}^\infty s_n \;dt \;\;\;\;\quad (10)$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty i_n = i(0) +\beta \int_0^t \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_n\; dt -(\gamma+\mu)\int_0^t \sum_{n=0}^\infty i_n \;dt \quad \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(11)$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r_n = r(0) +p\mu t +\gamma \int_0^t \sum_{n=0}^\infty i_n\; dt -\mu\int_0^t \sum_{n=0}^\infty r_n \;dt \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\quad(12)$$

from (10)-(12) we define the following scheme:

$$ s_0 = s(0)+(1-p)\mu t, \quad i_0=i(0), \quad r_0=r(0)+p\mu t \qquad\; (13)$$
$$s_{n+1} = -\beta \int_0^t F_n\; dt -\mu\int_0^t s_n \;dt \quad \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\quad \quad \qquad \quad \;\;\;(14)$$
$$i_{n+1} = \beta \int_0^t F_n\; dt -(\gamma+\mu)\int_0^t i_n \;dt \quad \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\quad \quad \quad \;\;\;\;\;(15)$$
$$r_{n+1} = \gamma \int_0^t i_n\; dt -\mu\int_0^t r_n \;dt \quad \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\quad \quad \quad \;\;\;\;\;\quad \quad \;\;\;(16)$$

using (9) we compute some Adomian polynomials as follows:

$$F_0 = s_0 i_0, \quad F_1 = s_0 i_0 +s_1 i_0, F_2 = s_0 i_2 +s_1 i_1 +s_2 i_0,$$ $$F_3 = s_0 i_3+s_1 i_2 +s_2 i_1 +s_3 i_0,\dots \quad \quad \qquad \qquad \quad (17)$$

Substituting (13)-(17) into (10)-(12) we should get this:

$$s_N = \sum_{n=0}^N s_n, \quad i_N = \sum_{n=0}^N i_n, \quad r_N = \sum_{n=0}^N r_n  \quad \quad \quad \;\;(18)$$

where
$$ s(t) =\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} s_N, \quad i(t) =\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} i_N, \quad r(t) =\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} r_N \quad \quad (19) $$

Comment: Difficult to access the paper. $28 €$ for two days !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I will add all the details then!